# Linux Mint 17.2 cinnamon takes too much time to boot and to be usable after login. What to do?

Tags: linux-mint, boot

I think I should track which startup script takes time such as printing starting and ending time of execution time with script name in another file.How can I do it? 
For details, I am using dual boot- linux mint and windows 10. And Windows 10 boots as usual [if this information helps to find the problem].

Comment: Similar issue here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269524/mint-17-2-kde-sluggish-after-login

Comment: @nemarona, Sadly that question also has no answer.